# How to implement aspects without using Springs as well as annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, aspects

I am currently trying to implement aspects for a dynamic web project. The problem is that IBM Websphere 6.0 which supports java version 1.3 and 1.4 only. I cannot implement aspects with annotations because for that I will need java 1.5 or higher. I do not want to use springs also. Is there any way through which I can implement aspects without using Springs and annotations.

Comment: Check out AspectJ at http://eclipse.org/aspectj/

Answer (score 1):

OMG, Java 1.4? Even Java 6 is unsupported nowadays. But @geoand is right, you can use AspectJ with compliance level 1.4. I would rather recommend upgrading to a more up to date JVM though.